# can I make custom event using standard metric or dimension provided by Firebase Analytics?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I understand that there are some [recommended events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en) for firebase analytics. one of the recommended events is [begin_checkout](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#begin_checkout) that already has associated standard custom parameter/dimension like `value` and `currency`.

I want to make my own custom event called `end_checkout` , and it also needs `value` and `currency` as the dimension and metric. so my code will be like this

```
await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
    name: "end_checkout",
    parameters: {
        "value": 99,
        "currency": "USD",
    },
);
```

as you can see, I try to make custom event, but I use parameter names  (dimension & metric) that already provided by Google. my question is.

can I make custom event using standard metric or dimension name that already provided by Firebase Analytics? or do I need to register custom dimension and custom metric called `value` and `currency` by myself?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a data card for each parameter to be added to the related event-detail report, you would need to register [custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use "value" and "currency" params in your custom events.  You will likely need to register them to see them in reports.